# Purescript inside Haskell code

Tags: haskell, purescript

I want to use a PureScript in the program code to generate text of JavaScript from it. For example, I use Julius (from Yesod) to directly insert a javascript. I want to use the same PureScript .Maybe there are such solutions or libraries?
Thank you!

Comment: You, basically, want a Purescript quasiquoter. This should be pretty easy to make up.

Comment: But I also need a compilation into the Javascript's text.

Comment: This is essentially asking how to write a compiler/interpreter for Purescript in Haskell targeting Javascript. This is much too broad for a SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have done something similar, I've kept the Purescript source in separate files, and combined the Haskell & Purescript parts later (during the build or at runtime).  I think this is the easiest way, and you can keep using existing Purescript tools.

I had my web server read the JS output from `purs` at runtime.  Another option would be to use `file-embed` to include the JS text when compiling the Haskell code.  One reason to prefer `file-embed` is if you need to have a single executable file to deploy.

Finally, I have a Makefile that builds the Purescript code, then the Haskell code.